# same category names are showing multiple times in the grid

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Same category names are showing multiple times in the grid.

My Query is something like this :

```
<%  SQLGetThumbList13="select CategoryID,CategoryName,ActiveFrom,ActiveUntil,HideCategory from categories where CategoryID="& RSGetThumbList12("CategoryID")
                set RSGetThumbList13= server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
RSGetThumbList13.CursorLocation=3
                RSGetThumbList13.open SQLGetThumbList13,UserConn, 3, 3, 1
                        ThumbCount13 = RSGetThumbList13.RecordCount
%>
```

I dont even need the category grid to show correctly, all i need is to show all category names for that bookid
but for some reason its only showing some records

```
<%  
'SQLGetThumbList12="select * from BooksAndCategories where BookID="& RSGetThumbList10("BookID")
SQLGetThumbList12="select * from BooksAndCategories as BooksCat inner join Categories as Cat " & _
                                           "ON BooksCat.CategoryID=Cat.CategoryID where BooksCat.BookID=" & RSGetThumbList10("BookID")
set RSGetThumbList12= server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
RSGetThumbList12.CursorLocation=3
RSGetThumbList12.open SQLGetThumbList12,UserConn, 3, 3, 1
ThumbCount12 = RSGetThumbList12.RecordCount
%>
```

My VB code

```
dim strVal1
 strVal1= request("str")
if(strVal1="unsold")then
SQLGetThumbList10="select * from Books where Sold=0;"
else
SQLGetThumbList10= "SELECT * FROM Books;"
end if
set RSGetThumbList10= server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
RSGetThumbList10.CursorLocation=3
RSGetThumbList10.open SQLGetThumbList10,UserConn, 3, 3, 1
ThumbCount10 = RSGetThumbList10.RecordCount
```

Comment: `Classic ASP` or `ASP.NET`?

Comment: I am using Classic ASP

Comment: Which one of these blocks of code is giving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to something like

```
"SELECT DISTINCT CategoryName FROM categories WHERE CategoryID=" & SGetThumbList12("CategoryID")
```